# How to use layout manager in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, jtabbedpane

I'm trying to make 3 tabs and in each tab, I have a text field and multiple button and check boxes and a big text area.

The problem is when I'm trying to use the  `GridBagLayout` or `GridLayout` with `JTabbedPane` at the same time, either it doesn't show anything or it brings all three tabs in one little box in the center. I don't know if we can use it both together?

But I would like to use some sort of layout to set the text filed on the top then in the middle of each tab use buttons and on the bottom of the tab have `JTextArea` for stream output.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class FrameFinder extends JFrame  {
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
    private final Font LARGE_FONT = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 34);
    public static JTextField text;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;
    private JMenuBar menubar;
    private KeyListener newkey;
    private JMenuItem exit;
    private JMenuItem about;
    private JTabbedPane jtap;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    static private final String newline = "\n";

    // constructor
    public FrameFinder(){
    }
    //creating constructor
    public FrameFinder(String str){
        createFrame(str);
        CreateTabbedPane();

    }

    // click listener
    private void addMenuListeners(){

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                exitActionPerformed();
            }
        });
        about.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
              //  aboutActionPerformed();
            }
        });
    }
    private void exitActionPerformed(){
        dispose();
    }


   //creating frame
    private void createFrame(String title) {
        setTitle(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }

        // here we create the tab bar
    public void CreateTabbedPane() {
      //  super(String.valueOf(new BorderLayout()));
        setTitle("Tabbed Pane");
        //setLayout(new GridLayout());
        jtap = new JTabbedPane();
        getContentPane().add(jtap);
        textArea = new JTextArea(50, 10);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
       // PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(textArea));
        //JPanel controls = new JPanel();
        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jp3 = new JPanel();


        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

        jp1.add(new JTextField("Find:", 20));
        jp1.add(new JButton("Search"));
        jp2.add(new JTextField("Directory path :", 20));
        jp2.add(new JButton("Browser "));
        jp1.add(new JCheckBox("match whole word."));
        jp1.add(new JCheckBox("Match case."));
        jp3.add(new JTextArea(50, 10));

        jp2.add(new JTextField("Find in folders:", 20));
        jp2.add(new JButton("Search"));
        jp2.add(new JTextField("Directory path :", 20));
        jp2.add(new JButton("Browser "));
        jp2.add(new JCheckBox("match whole word."));
        jp2.add(new JCheckBox("Match case."));
        jp3.add(new JTextArea(50, 10));

        jp3.add(new JTextField("Find in folders:", 20));
        jp3.add(new JButton("Search"));
        jp2.add(new JTextField("Directory path :", 20));
        jp2.add(new JButton("Browser "));
        jp3.add(new JCheckBox("match whole word."));
        jp3.add(new JCheckBox("Match case."));
        jp3.add(new JTextArea(50, 10));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
        JLabel labe13 = new JLabel();
       // label2.setText("You are in area of Tab2");
        createFrame("Finder");
        jp1.add(label1);
        jp2.add(label2);
        jp3.add(labe13);


        jtap.addTab("Find ", jp1);
        jtap.addTab("Replace All in one file", jp2);
        jtap.addTab("Replace All  in Multi files",jp3);

    }

}
```

Comment: `I know how to use the GridLayout on a single page but the problem is when I try to use in JTabbedPane` - that statement makes no sense. You don't use a GridLayout (or any layout) in a tabbed pane. You simply create a JTabbedPane and add it to the frame. Then you create a panel and add the panel to the tabbed pane. The "panel" you add to the tabbed panel uses a layout manager for the components you add to the panel. Read the JTabbedPane API and you will find a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tabbed Panes` where you will find a working example.

Comment: If you have problems with the above suggestion then post your [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.  So get one panel displaying on the tabbed pane before worrying about the others. As I suggested in your last question that you deleted https://stackoverflow.com/q/52683047/131872), you need to learn to simply the problem when you try to solve a problem and when you ask questions on the forum. We are not interested in the application, only the code directly related to the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
JPanel jp3 = new JPanel();


setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

The above code is setting the layout manager for the frame, which is not what you want to do.

And the default layout manager for a panel is a FlowLayout (since you don't specify the layout manager).

You want to set the layout manager for each panel:

```
JPanel jp1 = new JPanel( pick a layout manager);
JPanel jp2 = new JPanel( pick a layout manager);
JPanel jp3 = new JPanel( pick a layout manager);

//setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

So each panel you add to a tab can have a different layout manager to achieve your desired layout. And you can also nest panels with different layout managers to give you even more flexibility.

The layout of each tab is completely independent of the other tabs. The only relation is that all tabs share the same space so the preferred size of the tabbed pane will be the preferred size of the largest tab.

> But I would like to use some sort of layout to set the text filed on the top then in the middle of each tab use buttons and on the bottom of the tab have Jtextarea for stream output. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code:

So maybe you start with a BorderLayout for the main panel to add to the tab. Then you can create other panels as required to display the component in the PAGE_START, CENTER, PAGE_END of the BorderLayout. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for some examples to get you started.

Edit:

Following up on my suggestion from above you can do something like:

```
JPanel top = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 3) );
top.add( new JLabel("Label1") );
top.add( new JLabel("Label2") );
top.add( new JLabel("Label3") );

JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);

JPanel bottom = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 2) );
bottom.add( new JButton("Button1") );
bottom.add( new JButton("Button2") );

JPanel tab1 = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
tab1.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
tab1.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
tab1.add(bottom, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab1", tab1);

frame.add(tabbedPane);
```

Comment: Or alternatively `jp1.setLayout(...);`, etc.

Comment: well I tried to use the GroupLayout in side the  new JPanel( pick a layout manager) but it dosent let me to use it?  Can anyone give an example howto use the Grouplayout insde the JPanel jp1 = new JPanel( pick a layout manager);

Comment: `but it dosent let me to use it` - I have no idea what that means. Maybe you have an older version of Java?  So choose another layout manager. The tutorial has working examples that you can download and play with. In any case the GroupLayout would not be my first choice as it is the most complicated to use as you can tell by the demo code from the tutorial. I already gave you a suggestion on how I might approach the layout.

Comment: I've checked my java version and it's updated. is there any example that I can look see how they used GroupLayout in JTabbedPane!  for Gridlayout, I know how to use the GridLayout on a single page but the problem is when I try to use in JTabbedPane.

Comment: @Storeshah, see edit. If you still have a problem, then post an [mcve] like I just provided. The difference is that we will need to be able to compile and test the code. So you will need the main() method and a couple more statements to make the frame visible. All other code is irrelevant to your stated problem of doing layout management. When you simplify the code to 20 statements (or so) it is easy to understand.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to set a layout manager in JFrame, because you only are going to add one component: the jTabPane. By default all components are containers but just accept 1 component, if you want to add two or more components you need to set a layout manager. In this case you dont need to set a layout manager in Jframe, but you need to set a layout manager on every jpanel you add as a tab in teh jTabPane. Because you are not setting a layout manager on every jpanel, it will only display 1 component, the last added one.

I recommend you to use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), it is simple and very powerful.

Comment: (1-) `but you need to set a layout manager on every jpanel you add as a tab ` - already suggested. `Because you are not setting a layout manager on every jpanel, it will only display 1 component, the last added one` - not true. The default layout manager for a JPanel is a FlowLayout,